# Sound Problems!

Tags: sound

First off I am not getting any sound from my Asus XONAR DS... it was working fine in windows 7. After searching and not finding a solution I just puled the card out... Kind of a wast. Now I have sound working through the motherboard but I am also getting sound through from the case speaker as well. I have never had this problem before.

I am a bit new to Unity... So I could be missing the settings

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having sound issues. I haven't found an exact fix yet but mine works fine in Windows also and sounds similar to your issue. I am getting sound on my ASUS ve228 but not on my vt1720 PCI card.

What I have done to enable the sound on the card is reboot into recovery. Run the fix file systems then repair packages. Then reboot. Then it works for me but if I restart again it fails. Then I have to repeat the process.

It works and haven't had any issues other than having to do this almost every time I restart. It might at least get you by till you can fix it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot from any of the Linux LiveCDs.
On my **Toshiba Tecra A8** I tried **Puppy Linux 4**. I couldn't hear any sound when I booted from the **Puppy Linux 4**, but when I rebooted to my **Ubuntu 15.04** the sound was back. And in the audio settings there were *"Built-in Speakers"* instead of *"Dummy Output"* as my speakers.